# Text field with duplicate info

Tags: sed

I have a tab-delimited data file with text fields, where some fields have duplicate information, semicolon delimited:

```
2000;2000
05/19/2016;05/19/2016
foo;foo
```

How can I use `sed` to remove the duplicate part? Semicolons can regularly appear in other fields, so I think I need to search on a string found on both sides of a semicolon, bound by tabs, i.e. `\t$1;$1\t` (`\t` meant to represent tab), and then replace with the same instance `$1` without the semicolon and duplicated field. I'm open to other text-parsing commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSIXly:

```
sed -e 's/\([^;][^;]*\);\1/\1/g' <file
```

You can also use:

```
sed -E 's/([^;]+);\1/\1/g' <file
```

which was supported by GNU and BSD sed, and will become standard in next POSIX.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly if the duplicated field data contains a '`;`' as in `a;b;a;b` and it deletes the `;` from a field where it is not in the middle.

Comment: @Anthon: Yes, but the data is semicolon delimited.

Comment: No, the data is tab delimited according to the OP

Comment: @Anthon: I mean field data, as OP said `where some fields have duplicate information, semicolon delimited`

Comment: If I pipe '`acd;e`' into your sed command the semicolon gets deleted, the OP says that non-duplicating fields can have semicolons, so that cannot be correct IMO.

Comment: @Anthon: See my updated, I missed a `[^;]`, to behave like one or more.

Comment: Yes, now it behaves correctly on the testdata I made for myself.

Answer (score 1):

With this in the file `tabbed.input` (no spaces all consequetive whitespaces are a single tab):

```
abc     bd      c       2000;2000       d       2;00;2;01
e       05/19/2016;05/19/2016   foo;foo f       g
```

the following Python program:

```
def cleaned(f):
    length = len(f)
    if (length % 2) == 0:
        return f  # even number of characters in field, middle one never ';'
    half_way = length // 2
    if f[half_way] != ';':
        return f
    before, after = f[:half_way], f[half_way+1:]
    if before == after:
        return before
    return f

with open('tabbed.input') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        fields = line[:-1].split('\t')
        cleaned_fields = [cleaned(f) for f in fields]
        print('\t'.join(cleaned_fields))
```

your output will be:

```
012345670123456701234567012345670123456701234567
abc     bd      c       2000    d       2;00;2;01
e       05/19/2016      foo     f       g
```

By testing for an even number of characters and having a '`;`' in the middle of a field this will even work when the duplicated data contains a '`;`'

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```perl
perl -F'\t' -e 'map {s/(.+);$1/$1/} @F; print join("\t",@F)'
```

Unlike the `sed` solution, this processes each field individually, which prevents the possibility of a cross-field duplicate being detected and deleted (e.g. `foo;<TAB>foo` - the TAB and the second `foo` are deleted by the `sed` solution, but not by this `perl` solution).  Depending on your input data, this is probably not a problem in your real world usage.

The following version gets rid of multiple duplicates in a field (e.g. `a;b;a;b;a;b` --> `a;b`):

```perl
perl -F'\t' -e 'map {while(/(.+);$1/) {s/(.+);$1/$1/g}} @F;print join("\t",@F)'
```

NOTE: these assume a recent version of `perl`, where `-F` implies `-a` and `-n`.  If you have an older version, use `perl -F'\t' -ane '...'`